# What the File class in java.io package represent?

Tags: java, file, io

I am a little bit confuse about what the File class represent because some people says that it's does not describe a File but rather a Path, and the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) says "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames. So, what is the correct sentence ?

Comment: The correct sentence is always the sentence in the documentation. What is unclear in this sentence to you?

Comment: It's a class that represents a file and corresponding information.

Comment: What people? Who? What is their credibility compared to the Javadoc?

Comment: Try *an abstract representation of **file** (and **directory**) **pathnames***. It isn't the file, just a representation of where the file **is** on the system.

Answer (score 1):

It represents a file system *pathname* (absolute or relative).  The pathname may or may not correspond to an actual file or directory.

---

> So, what is the correct sentence ?

The javadoc is correct.  The javadoc is **always** correct ... because it is the specification of the Java standard class libraries.

(And the people who say that a `File` is a path are also correct.  They are saying what the javadoc says ...)

---

Example:

```
File dir = new File("weeble");
System.out.println(dir.exists());  // Prints false
dir.mkdir();                       // Assume this returns true ....
System.out.println(dir.exists());  // Prints true
```

At the start, the `File` represents the pathname for a file system object that doesn't exist.  Then we call `mkdir()`, and after that the `File` represents the path of a directory that does exist.  However, some other application (or some other thread of this application) could remove the "weeble" directory, and the `File` would once again represent the pathname of a non-existent object.

For the record, there is no Java class that definitively represents a "file" or a "directory".  The lifecycle of file system objects is managed by the operating system, and the POSIX syscall APIs do not provide the functionality to tie these objects with application objects.  Hence Java cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: when you create a File object, it might not correspond to anything at all on the hard disk yet. At that moment you might choose to create it as a directory (mkdir() or mkdirs()) or as a file, streaming content into it.

Its stringified value could represent pretty much anything from a simple file or folder name, relative file or folder name. Or it can represent an absolute file or folder name, too, in the format required by your OS (e.g. with driver letters on Windows).

It really should have been called Path from the get go. But no matter, there is [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) interface since Java 7. Modern computer users mean document (with content) when they say file, but according to old Unix/POSIX terminology and mantra (many decades ago), 'everything was a file', including actual directories.

Answer (score 0):

It represents a single file or directory.

For example, in:

```
File f = new File("/home/mytextfile.txt");
File p = f.getParentFile()
```

the variable f is a text file. The variable p represents the parent folder containing that text file, which is /home/ in this case.